# How to remove the Android WebView print added margin?

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, google-cloud-print

We tries to print a webview content over google cloud print, but no matter what we do the resulted printout adds some margin.

Is there a way to remove this margin?
We tried:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
```

then

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

then

```
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

none worked...

Comment: I don't know if it affects printing but `html{margin:0; padding:0;}` works miracles.

Comment: This might seem daft, but have you tried with `!important` in the style attribute as well? And same on the root node, `html` i.e. `html, body{ margin: 0 !important; padding:0 !important; }`? Could always set `border` to 0 just in case. Alternatively, perhaps try this in your CSS: `@page{ margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; }`

Comment: We tried it all, it seems like the margin is not related to the html but a constant margin the webview is adding when trying to print

Answer (score 9):

Use the following code to remove margins when printing the WebView.

```
@page{
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it for me!

Answer (score 6):

Just Use It *{margin:0px; padding:0px} Add In Your Style Sheet And Check Once

```
  *{margin:0px; padding:0px}
    body,html{padding:0px;margin:0px;}
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Answer (score 1):

By Default HTML web pages have a padding and margin of 10px; You have to set in your head section or or css file:

```
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  }
```

It's work for me. Hope it will help you :)

**or you can try another one:**

Replace your tag with this one:

```
<body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>
```

Here's another tip for images in a webview: add a styling that fits images in the width of the screen. Works great on all screen sizes:

```
<style type='text/css'>
      img {max-width: 100%;height:initial;} div,p,span,a {max-width: 100%;}
   </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using the css doesn't solve your issue, you can try using a TextView with fromHtml instead of using a webview:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
Spanned textviewHtml;

//Note : fromHtml needs a display flag as second argument from API 24
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
    textviewHtml= Html.fromHtml(yourHtmlHere, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
}
else {
    textviewHtml= Html.fromHtml(yourHtmlHere);
}

myTextView.setText(textviewHtml);
```

For more options on fromHtml you can refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Hope this helps! ;-)